# How to see the email addresses that are present in two different documents?

Tags: email-filter

I have a couple of .PDF and .DOC documents that contains thousands of email addresses in them. I want to know which email addresses are duplicates. Yes, the documents have more content than just the email addresses.

I want to see (not remove) the actual email addresses that are present in two different documents. When I say I want to "see", that means, I want to harvest those actual email addresses that are present in two different documents. I do not mind if the program "removes" the duplicates from two different documents, as long as I can see these duplicate email addresses and not simply removed and I do not know what has been removed. I want to know which email addresses are duplicates.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community I know you are a robot, but for the benefit of other readers, my answer is: The question is indeed limited to a specific problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the documents have more content than just the email addresses?

A non-scripting approach would be

1. extract email addresses to file
2. sort
3. remove duplicates
4. diff result of (2) with (3)

### 1) Convert document to list of email addresses

- Install [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and copy your document into it
- Open "Find and Replace"
- Find: `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)` // Vaguely accurate email regex
- Replace: `\r\n$&\r\n`
- Make sure "Regular expression" option is checked

Now you have each email on its own line.
Switch to the "Mark" tab and repeat the search, this time "Bookmarking" the lines
[image: using notepad++ Mark feature]

Now remove unmarked lines: `Search > Bookmark > Remove Unmarked Lines`

### 2) Sort lines

`Edit -> Line Operations -> Sort Lines Lexographically Ascending`

Save a copy of this file.

### 3) Remove duplicates

Install [TextFX](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/TextFX) plugin to Notepad++

Sort again, but check "Sort outputs only Unique"
[image: TextFX]

### 4) Diff

Use a "diff tool" ([WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/) or the "[Compare To](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/)" Notepad++ plugin) to compare the "sorted list with duplicates" with the "sorted list without duplicates" to yield the list of duplicated emails

Credit to https://www.kniko.net/how-to-extract-email-addresses-from-a-text-file-using-notepad-with-no-coding-at-all/ for images and email regex

Comment: yes, "the documents have more content than just the email addresses". So, I need to first convert the PDF file or DOC file into a TEXT file? You wrote, "Use ... WinMerge or the "Compare To" Notepad++ plugin)". Where can I download the '"Compare To" Notepad++ plugin'? Thank you.

Comment: You'll inevitably have to be manipulating the text, yes. Simply selecting all text and pasting into notepad++ should be sufficient. I added a link for CompareTo.

Comment: Note that email addresses may be hyphenated in a PDF, these will end up on two separate lines when copying / pasting to a text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an online service:

- Select all the text in the document
- Use the browser to navigate to
  [Email Extractor For Web Pages and Text](http://www.convertcsv.com/email-extractor.htm)
- Paste your text
- Under "Step 3: Extract Emails", click Extract
- The emails will be displayed.